# Solving for the deviation in the polymer volume fraction under the random phase approximation

Tags: statistical-thermodynamics, polymers

I am reading through Introduction to Polymer Physics by Doi, and I am studying the concentration fluctuation in polymer solutions, specifically the random phase approximation. For the most part, I understand the logic, until they try to solve for the volume fractions from the following three equations:
\begin{align}
\overline{\delta \phi _A (r)} &= -\beta \int dr' S_{AA}^0 (r-r')[u_A(r')+w_A(r')+V(r')]\label{1}\tag{1}\\
\overline{\delta \phi _B (r)} &= -\beta \int dr' S_{BB}^0 (r-r')[u_B(r')+w_B(r')+V(r')]\label{2}\tag{2}\\
\end{align}
Using the constraint relation $\phi _A(r) + \phi_B(r) = 1$, we have
$$\overline{\delta \phi _A (r)} + \overline{\delta \phi_B (r)}=0\label{3}\tag{3}$$
The objective is to solve the above 3 equations.
We also have the following definitions:
\begin{align}
w_A(r) &= -z[\epsilon_{AA}\overline{\phi _A(r)}+\epsilon _{AB} \overline{\phi _B (r)}] \label{4}\tag{4}\\
w_B(r) &= -z[\epsilon _{BA}\overline{\phi_A(r)}+\epsilon _{BB}\overline{\phi_B (r)}]\label{5}\tag{5}
\end{align}
They use Fourier transform to solve these equations and I don't quite understand the process. This is how Doi puts it forward:
To solve the above equations, we will use the Fourier transform defined as follows:
\begin{align}
\overline{\phi _{Aq}}=\int dr e^{iq\cdot r}\overline{\delta \phi _A (r)}=\int dr e^{iq\cdot r}\overline{\phi _A (r)}\label{6}\tag{6}
\end{align}
(And then suddenly) the above equations take the form
\begin{align}
\overline{\phi_{A}} = -\beta S_{AA}^0[u_A-z(\epsilon _{AA}\overline{\phi_A}+\epsilon_{AB} \overline{\phi _B}) +V)]\label{7}\tag{7} \\
\overline{\phi_{B}} = -\beta S_{BB}^0[u_B-z(\epsilon _{BA}\overline{\phi_A}+\epsilon_{BB} \overline{\phi _B}) +V)]\label{8}\tag{8}
\end{align}

My question is, how did he get to the above equations from the Fourier transforms? I am confused about the math here, if anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doi makes this slightly more confusing because just after these equations, he writes:

> Here for simplicity we have dropped the subscript q.

So all of the pieces of your Eqs \eqref{7} and \eqref{8} are actually the Fourier transforms of the pieces of your \eqref{1} and \eqref{2}, so they should all have q subscripts. Its also common to write Fourier transformed functions as $\tilde{f}(q)$ to emphasize that it is not the same functional form as $f(r)$.

The reason the integral disappears is actually due to a general result called the [Convolution Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem). A convolution of two functions $f$ and $g$ is defined as $$f(r)*g(r)\equiv\int f(r-r')g(r')dr'=\int f(r')g(r-r')dr'\tag{1}$$
The Convolution theorem states that $$\mathcal{F}[f(r)*g(r)]=\tilde{f}(q)\cdot \tilde{g}(q)\tag{2}$$
where $\mathcal{F}$ is the Fourier transform. This means convolutions in real space become products in the reciprocal space (and vice versa).

Because your \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} have the form of a convolution, their Fourier transforms are just the products of the Fourier transform of $S_{AA/BB}$ with the Fourier transform of each potential term.